# Change thumbnail dynamic display counter

Tags: php, mysql

In sample #1, I am able to intermix values called from a mysql database by changing the column name.  You will notice I use ListingRid for the src= and alt= uses MLNumber.

```
<div id="loadarea" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"><img width="400" height="300" src="http://www.mydomain/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/<?php echo(rawurlencode($row['ListingRid'])); ?>_1.jpg" alt="<?php echo(rawurlencode($row['MLNumber'])); ?>" align="left"  border="0"></div>
```

Farther down in the page, i have a second sample here I have a block of PHP code and I need to change out the use of $MLNumber with $ListingRid but when I do the same thing and change the column name it does not carry the value through and I end up with just .jpg instead of the $ListingRid.  What am I doing wrong and can you show me a sample so I can learn what the issue is?

```
<?php

   $image = "<br>";
   $img_cnt = 1;
   $image .= "<a href=/images/$MLNumber.jpg rel=\"enlargeimage\" rev=\"targetdiv:loadarea,trigger:click\"><img src=/images/$MLNumber.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' /></a>&nbsp;";

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried making sure that your variables contain the data you think they do and that the rawurlencode($row['ListingRid']) actually returns what you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you declaring `$MLNumber`?  In the first code sample you're referencing the result set with `$row['MLNumber']`

Do you have a line `$MLNumber = $row['MLNumber'];` somewhere and just haven't pasted it in this code sample or is it missing from your code?

Comment: perfect, yes...I was missing declaring $ListingRid ...appreciate it!